# How data are being feed into LSTM cell

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

Hi everyone I want to learn about training many-to-one Long Short Term Memory (LSTM) for classification. My datasets configurations are consists of 100 rows, 44 frames, 13 features. I want to feed that data into say 32 LSTM cell followed by dense with softmax function (4 class). I am confused about how each rows being feed into 32 LSTM cell . 
 
Which statement below is the correct one?

1. If the time step is 44, does the first frame go through all 32 LSTM cell, followed by the second frame go through all 32 LSTM cell, until the 44th frame?
2. The first frame will be feed into the first LSTM cell, the second frame will be feed into the second LSTM cell, until the 32th frame feed into the 32th LSTM cell. If this is the correct statement, how about 12 frames left? Or the number of LSTM cell must be larger than the number of frames ?

Please explain which statement is correct and why. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean a layer with 32 lstm cells? The examples folder in the keras repository may be of use to you

Comment: yes, I meant 1 layer which consists of 32 LSTM cells

Comment: Did you stack the lstm cells vertically or horizontally?

Comment: I stack the lstm cell horizontally

Comment: Are you feeding all the 44 time steps in one shot from the data as it is or are you modifying the data to shorter time steps?

Comment: actually 44 time steps are being obtained by extraction features. So I'm not modifying anything

Comment: So your data goes into each lstm by its turn as batch size x 44 x 13. The 44 frames are fed into the lstm in one shot